# Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit disk allocation issue

Tags: partitioning, windows-server-2012-r2

Looks like the UI of Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit changed a lot. Wondering how to 
allocate the unallocated 60G to Disk C? Thanks.

Here is the screen snapshot of server manager, disk/storage.

[image]

regards,
Lin

Comment: You need to add more details what view is this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same good old `Disk Management`?

[image]
[image]

Or,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details guide Tom, vote up and mark your reply as answer. :)